# Unable to write to disk using GridFSFile in springboot 2.0.2

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Trying to use code in:

http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-data/springdata-mongodb-gridfstemplate-save-retrieve-delete-binary-files-image-text-files

with springboot 1.5.13.
In this code to retrieve an image use GridFSDBFile like this:

```
GridFSDBFile imageFile = gridOperations.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(imageFileId)));
```

and later to save in filesystem use this:

```
imageFile.writeTo
```

Baeldung has the same code:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-gridfs

I have my project in springboot 2.0.2 and this line:

```
GridFSDBFile imageFile = gridOperations.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(imageFileId)));
```

throws an error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from GridFSFile to GridFSDBFile
```

so, once I have changed to:

```
GridFSFile imageFile = gridOperations.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(imageFileId)));
```

no errors, but now I have not available the method:

```
writeTo
```

to write to disk.

UPDATE 1:

```
imageFileId = "5b0bff8b7cc45b32f43b47f4";

        GridFSFile imageFile = gridOperations.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(imageFileId)));
try {
            File file = new File("c:/JSA/retrieve/" + imageFile.getFilename());
            FileOutputStream streamToDownloadTo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            //This line doesn't works
            gridFSBucket.downloadToStream(imageFile.getId(), streamToDownloadTo);
            streamToDownloadTo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
            System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("error1: " + e1.getMessage());
        }
```

UPDATE 2:

```
try {
            File file = new File("c:/JSA/retrieve/" + imageFile.getFilename());
            FileOutputStream streamToDownloadTo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            System.out.println("imageFile.getId(): " + imageFile.getId());
            System.out.println("streamToDownloadTo: " + streamToDownloadTo.toString());
            gridFSBucket.downloadToStream(imageFile.getId(), streamToDownloadTo);
            streamToDownloadTo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
            System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("error1: " + e1.getMessage());
        }
```

Console

```
imageFile.getId(): BsonObjectId{value=5b0bff8b7cc45b32f43b47f4}
streamToDownloadTo: java.io.FileOutputStream@3b20c8e2
```

**This line thrown an exception:**

```
gridFSBucket.downloadToStream(imageFile.getId(), streamToDownloadTo);
```

and return **null**

---

## Solved

Inject:

```
 @Autowired
    MongoGridFsTemplate mongoGridFsTemplate;


GridFSBucket gridFSBucket = GridFSBuckets.create(mongoGridFsTemplate.mongoDbFactory().getDb());
imageFileId = "5b0bff8b7cc45b32f43b47f4";
    
GridFSFile imageFile = gridOperations.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId(imageFileId))));
    
            try {
                File file = new File("c:/JSA/retrieve/" + imageFile.getFilename());
                FileOutputStream streamToDownloadTo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                gridFSBucket.downloadToStream(imageFile.getId(), streamToDownloadTo);
                streamToDownloadTo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle exception
                System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Did you look at the MongoDB Java driver reference? http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/driver/tutorials/gridfs/#download-from-gridfs  You didn't say which version of the driver you're using but you can change the version of the reference in the top left of the page.

Comment: according the project springboot has installed 3.6.3. Added code from repository but I get null....

Comment: I think I see what's wrong: try `is(new ObjectId(imageFileId))`

Comment: Changed, but, GridFSFile imageFile = gridOperations.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId(imageFileId))));  getting null again.....Query retrieve the info correctly, problem is storing

Comment: I was guessing because you didn't say what is null. So...what is null?

Comment: take a look to update 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172316/discussion-between-paul-and-davisoski).

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.